# Merge multiple arrays by key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am trying to combine multiple items from a large data set. Basically I want to firstly filter the items (IE only do this on certain objects), then return keys I pass it.

I am probably taking the completely wrong approach in my example. It needs to be pretty flexible- as the data may have keys missing (eg `foo` will not be present on every item).

I believe this should be done with a reduce?

Sample code: https://jsfiddle.net/rxLgm4nw/35/

```
const data = { a: { foo: "x", bar: ["y"] }, b: { foo: "1", bar: ["z"] } };

const checkObjs = ["a", "b"];

const keysToReturn = ["foo", "bar"];

const res = checkObjs
  .map(key => {
    return keysToReturn.map(area => {
      if (data[key][area]) {
        return { [area]: data[key][area] };
      }
    });
  })
  .reduce((x, y) => [...x, ...y], []);
```

**DESIRED RESULT**

```
[{
    foo: ['x', '1'],
    bar: ['y', 'z']
}]
```

Comment: I didn't see `z` in your `data` array.

Comment: and your input data is also inconsistent about whether the value is a single value, or a value inside an array.

Comment: I have updated. Now is consistent, including example on jsfiddle

Comment: @Ycon There's no `2` in your data.  Is it right to assume you want `foo` to equal `['x', '1']` and `bar` to equal `['y', 'z']` from the data visible?

Comment: is it supposed to be `foo: ['x', '1'], bar: ['y', 'z']`? your desired result seems wrong `foo: ['x', 'z'], bar: ['1', '2']`

Comment: Ok fixed the example. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my solution. I think this is what you are looking for:

```
const data = { a: { foo: "x", bar: ["y"] }, b: { foo: "1", bar: ["z"] } }
const checkObjs = ["a", "b"]
const keysToReturn = ["foo", "bar"]

const result = keysToReturn.reduce((acc, item) => {
    acc[item] || (acc[item] = [])
    checkObjs.forEach(key => {
        acc[item] = acc[item].concat(data[key][item])
    })
    return acc
}, {})

console.log([result])
```

Comment: You can replace the two internal lines with a single one: `acc[item] = acc[item].concat(data[key][item]);`

Comment: @ChatterOne Thanx!

Comment: Seems like an elegent solution! Just quickly- it does add empty strings in the array though. Is there a way to remove them?

Comment: @Ycon Yes, you can do it like this: ```acc[item] = acc[item].concat([].concat(data[key][item])[0] || [])```

Answer (score 0):

If you're not sure how to use reduce or map, you can always stick to the basics.

It might not be as elegant and/or performant, but it gets the job done.

```
const data = {
    a: {
        foo: 'x',
        bar: ['y']
    },
    b: {
        foo: '1',
        bar: ['z']
    }
}

var res = {};

const checkObjs = {
    a: 1,
    b: 1
};

const keysToReturn = {
    foo: 1,
    bar: 1
};

for (var k in data) {
    if (k in checkObjs) {
        for (var k2 in data[k]) {
            if (k2 in keysToReturn) {
                if (typeof res[k2] === 'undefined') {
                    res[k2] = [];
                }
                res[k2] = res[k2].concat(data[k][k2]);
            }
        }
    }
}

console.log('data!', res)
```